# Libusb and how to use its packages in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu, installation, libusb

I have installed libusb by using the following command. I am not sure if it was right or not and the command was

```
sudo apt-get install libusb-dev
```

Once I have installed (and I am not sure if it has installed or not because I am a novice user of Ubuntu), I want to know how would I use the library, because I write some sample code which uses <libusb.h>, but when I compile that C++ file using

```
g++ test_libusb.cpp
```

that throws the following error,

> test_libusb.cpp:2:20: fatal error: libusb.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.

I am clueless what to do. I can't find any source on the Internet to get to the bottom of this...

I want to know two things here:

1. How do I add the libusb library in C/C++ so I can use <libusb.h>?
2. What would some sample code be? Only a few lines to see if libusb is working...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/i386/libusb-dev/filelist: The file you want to include is `usb.h`. Also, you'll have to tell the compiler where it can find the compiled library functions: Add `-lusb` to the compiler command line to make it load `libusb.so`.

Comment: as i said i am a novice if you see that page 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722083/how-to-use-libusb-and-libusb-get-device-descriptor
in above example they have used libusb example as i mentioned '#incluce <libusb.h>'

Comment: @UsmanSharifAmjadKhan: Well, at least on debianish systems, the include file is named `usb.h`, not `libusb.h`, so you'll need to use `#include <usb.h>`.

Answer (score 10):

Try including it like so:

```
#include <libusb-1.0/libusb.h>
```

and then compile it like so:

```
g++ main.cpp -o main -lusb-1.0
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I use Fedora 24 and libusb is located at /usr/include/libusb-1.0/libusb.h adding the '-1.0' to '-lusb-1.0' fixed everything

Answer (score 6):

Actually at least in Debian 7.4 (wheezy), and probably in Ubuntu also, there are two distinct libusb packages: `libusb-dev` (0.1.12-20+nmu1) and `libusb-1.0-0-dev` (1.0.11-1).  Confusingly, they can both be installed concurrently and provide header files in different locations:

```
$ dpkg -L libusb-dev|grep /usr/include
/usr/include
/usr/include/usb.h
$ dpkg -L libusb-1.0-0-dev|grep /usr/include
/usr/include
/usr/include/libusb-1.0
/usr/include/libusb-1.0/libusb.h
```

Answer (score 5):

Try `#include <usb.h>`. The "lib" is part of the Linux naming convention, i.e. library "foo" has header `foo.h` and is called `libfoo-dev` in the Debian package structure, and linked as `-lfoo`, and the compiled library files are called `libfoo.a` and `libfoo.so`.

Comment: It's linked using `-lfoo`, not `-libfoo`.