# C Programming - Accessing USB Data / Driver Specifics

Tags: c, automation, usb

I am writing some simple test automation to access the USB port in Ubuntu, and determine driver specific details, devices that are connected, and operating mode (USB 2 , 3 , etc ...).

I have not done any development in this area, and was looking for advice on libraries / recommendations to accomplish this.

Thank you for you help!

Dan.

Comment: http://www.libusb.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this using libusb.  You can get get started here.  http://libusb.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/  If you're just looking at seeing various usb devices, it's pretty easy.  Here are some examples that you can get up and running pretty quickly: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/148707-introduction-to-using-libusb-10/

Answer (score 0):

I found the sourceforge info useful, but could not get the install to work in Ubuntu.

After some searching, I found [Libusb and how to use its packages in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15041310/libusb-and-how-to-use-its-packages-in-ubuntu)

This appears to resolve my issue; plus interesting point about using usb.h instead of libusb.h to compile.

Thanks for all the input!

Dan